# Тестовые базы данных

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite

Как создать тестовую базу данных? В онлайн-песочнице или, например, в Microsoft SQL Server. Конкретно нужно создать две таблицы и поиграться с запросами, что да как работает.

Comment: также как и не тестовую.

Comment: Возьмите готовую. См. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/downloading-sample-databases

Comment: Как создать: sql-запросами `create database`, `create table`, `insert`. | Если хотите найти готовую, то, во-первых, это не формат этого сайта, во-вторых, просто вбейте в любой поисковик "название_СУБД test database"

Comment: Если вы читаете какой-то учебник/самоучитель, то там всегда будут примеры создания и заполнения БД. Или сказано, где найти готовую.

Answer (score 1):

Я не очень понимаю, а какие у Вас возникают проблемы при создании тестовой базы данных?

Если Вы используете MS SQL - то у Вас есть SQL Management Studio - графический инструмент, сильно облагчающий работу на первых порах. В MySQL у Вас есть SQL workbench.

И там буквально всё делается по правому клику мышкой: создание баз, создание таблиц и т.п.